# How to select rows where column value IS NOT NULL using CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, null

I'm using CodeIgniter's Active Record class to query the MySQL database. I need to select the rows in a table where a field is not set to NULL:

```
$this->db->where('archived !=', 'NULL');
$q = $this->db->get('projects');
```

That only returns this query:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE archived != 'NULL';
```

The `archived` field is a `DATE` field.

Is there a better way to solve this? I know I can just write the query myself, but I want to stick with the Active Record throughout my code.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
where('archived IS NOT NULL', null, false)
```

Comment: Please note that when you set this third parameter to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

Comment: Also worth adding that you can use this when you're passing an array parameter: `where(array("foo" => "bar", "archived IS NOT NULL" => null))`. Pretty unintuitive but works.

Answer (score 69):

The Active Record definitely has some quirks. When you pass an array to the `$this->db->where()` function it will generate an IS NULL. For example:

```
$this->db->where(array('archived' => NULL));
```

produces

```
WHERE `archived` IS NULL
```

The quirk is that there is no equivalent for the negative `IS NOT NULL`. There is, however, a way to do it that produces the correct result and still escapes the statement:

```
$this->db->where('archived IS NOT NULL');
```

produces

```
WHERE `archived` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1 because `where('archived IS NOT NULL')` this still protects identifiers and accepted answer doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

**CodeIgniter 3**

Only:

```
$this->db->where('archived IS NOT NULL');
```

The generated query is:

```
WHERE archived IS NOT NULL;
```

> $this->db->where('archived IS NOT NULL',**null**,**false**);  << Not necessary

**Inverse:**

```
$this->db->where('archived');
```

The generated query is:

```
WHERE archived IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 7):

Null must not be set to string...

```
$this->db->where('archived IS NOT', null);
```

It works properly when null is not wrapped into quotes.

Comment: @GusDeCooL Not sure this actually works.
Using this output ..." field IS NOT" without the NULL. The accepted answer seems to be the way to do it properly.
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/119444/#593454 - gives more info that I ever could.

Comment: -1 because it doesn't work!
I tried a similar variation of this:
  $this->db->where('when_removed is', null);
gave a database error and showed the query generated included:
  ...WHERE "when_removed" is ORDER BY "last_name" asc...

Answer (score 5):

Much better to use following:

**For is not null:**

```
where('archived IS NOT NULL', null);
```

**For is null:**

```
where('archived', null);
```

update

We can use without second parameter for where in CodeIgniter's Active Record is not needed when checking for NULL or IS NOT NULL. Here's the correct usage:

For IS NOT NULL:

```
$this->db->where('archived IS NOT NULL');
$q = $this->db->get('projects');
```

For IS NULL:

```
$this->db->where('archived IS NULL');
$q = $this->db->get('projects');
```

In both cases, you don't need to provide a second parameter. The where method automatically handles NULL comparisons correctly without the need for an explicit second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

And just to give you yet another option, you can use `NOT ISNULL(archived)` as your WHERE filter.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter generates an "IS NULL" query by just leaving the call with no parameters:

```
$this->db->where('column');
```

The generated query is:

```
WHERE `column` IS NULL
```

Comment: OP is looking for `IS NOT NULL` not `IS NULL`

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do (if you want to test NULL)

```
$this->db->where_exec('archived IS NULL)
```

If you want to test NOT NULL

```
$this->db->where_exec('archived IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Where are you finding this `where_exec()` method?  I don't see it anywhere in my CI project and I can't find a single resource online that speaks of its name.  Please support this answer with a link to documentation.

Answer (score -1):

$this->db->or_where('end_date IS', 'NULL', false);

Comment: Question's title: "_How to select rows where column value IS NOT NULL using CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord?_"

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **multi where** in your model like:

```
function getCommonRecords($id, $tbl_name, $multi_where='') {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('isDeleted', '0');
    if ($id > 0) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
    }
    if ($multi_where != '') {
        foreach ($multi_where as $key => $val) {
            $this->db->where($key, $val);
        }
    }
    $queryResult = $this->db->get($tbl_name);
    return $queryResult->result_array();
}
```

Then I would recommend using the following syntax that will bypass the second parameter in calculating the multi where condition.

```
 $this->api->getCommonRecords(NULL,'contracts', ['id' =>,'party1Sign IS NOT NULL'=>NULL,'party2Sign IS NOT NULL'=>null]);
```

Answer (score -2):

One way to check either column is null or not is

```
$this->db->where('archived => TRUE);
$q = $this->db->get('projects');
```

in php if column has data, it can be represent as True otherwise False
To use multiple comparison in where command and to check if column data is not null 
 do it like

here is the complete example how I am filter  columns in where clause (Codeignitor). The last one show **Not NULL** Compression

```
$where = array('somebit' => '1', 'status' => 'Published', 'archived ' => TRUE );
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: I just tried this and output the SQL it generates: `SELECT * FROM (\`test\`) WHERE \`somebit\` = '1' AND \`status\` = 'Published' AND \`sc_id\` = 1`. Checking if a column is equal to 1 and checking if a column is not null are extremely different.