# Codeigniter Where clause

Tags: codeigniter

Somehow its a bit difficult to for me to build a query like this:
Give me all entries of navigation where linkname not null

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('navigation',array('linkname'!==NULL));
```

Giving me Error

> Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT `linkname`, `idnavigation` FROM (`navigation`) WHERE `0` = 1

Any hints with this?

Comment: Dunno why this question has been downvoted. Helped me. I had `$query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('column', 'value'));` and had this issue. Needed to change `'column', 'value'` to `'column' => 'value'`. Silly error, but thanks for helping. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate [querying-mysql-with-codeigniter-selecting-rows-where-field-is-null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489453/querying-mysql-with-codeigniter-selecting-rows-where-field-is-null/13995884#13995884)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply write the `WHERE` clause manually like this:

```
$this->db->get_where('navigation', 'linkname IS NOT NULL');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's :

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('navigation',array('linkname !=' => NULL));
```

Comment: I think its important to note that there should be a space between the field name and the operator (i.e 'linkname!=' will not work)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
$this->db->select("*)
->from("table_name")
->where("your_id <>",'');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$this->db->where('linkname !==', NULL);
$query = $this->db->get('navigation');
```