# Value IS NOT NULL in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create the following statement:

```
select * from donors where field is NOT NULL;
```

With codeigniter, my code looks like this:

```
$where = ['field' => NULL];
$this->db->get_where('table', $where);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109047/codeigniter-where-clause)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

when you see [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#looking-for-specific-data) You can use `$this->db->where()` with third parameter set to FALSE to not escape your query.
Example:

```
$this->db->where('field is NOT NULL', NULL, FALSE);
```

Or you can use custom query string like this

```
$where = "field is  NOT NULL";
$this->db->where($where);
```

So your query builder will look like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('field is NOT NULL', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->get('donors');
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('*');
$where = "field is  NOT NULL";
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->get('donors');
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$this -> db -> get_where('donors', array('field !=' => NULL));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have some a complex query with multiple where and Having condition.

Please find below example:

```
$this->db->select(['id', 'email_address', 'abandon_at','datediff(now(),`abandon_at`) AS daysdiff ' ]); 
$this->db->having('daysdiff < 11');
$query = $this->db->get_where('forms', array('abandon_form' => 1,'abandon_at !=' => 'NULL') );   
return $query->result();
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case I had to make sure 'NULL' was in quotes like in this example: `'abandon_at !=' => 'NULL'`

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('columnName !=', null);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please elaborate a bit to explain how your answer works and how it is different from accepted answer.