# check value is blank in where clause in codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter

I've following code. I've use left join for tbl_meeting_invite.

```
$this->db->where('meeting_created_by','1');
$this->db->join('tbl_meeting_invite','invite_meeting_id=meeting_id','left');
$this->db->where('meeting_created_by','1');
$this->db->or_where('invite_user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$this->db->group_by('invite_meeting_id');
$data['invited_list']=$this->db->get('tbl_meeting');
```

I want to check if invite_user_id is not blank then $this->db->or_where('invite_user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id')); should check. how could in I check this in query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076281/value-is-not-null-in-codeigniter

Comment: But this is check value is null or not correct?

Comment: $this->db->where('field', '');

Comment: I want to check if field is not blank then where condition is check. Not field is blank or not

Comment: $this->db->where('field !=', '');

Comment: Please check my question properly. If invite_user_id has any value then only $this->db->or_where('invite_user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id')); should check. I don't want to check invite_user_id is blank or not so that  $this->db->where('field', ''); is not usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this syntax?

```
    $this->db->where('meeting_created_by','1');
$this->db->join('tbl_meeting_invite','invite_meeting_id=meeting_id','left');
$this->db->where('meeting_created_by','1');
$this->db->or_where('IF(invite_user_id IS NULL OR invite_user_id = '', '', '.$this->session->userdata('user_id')),NULL,FALSE);
$this->db->group_by('invite_meeting_id');
$data['invited_list']=$this->db->get('tbl_meeting');
```