# Value is NULL Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

Im trying to create the following statement (which works):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS item_count FROM message WHERE user_id_to = '1' AND read_date IS NULL GROUP BY message_id
```

With Codeigniters Active Record. My code looks like this:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('message');
$this->db->where('user_id_to', $this->session->userdata('id'));
$this->db->where(array('read_date' => NULL));
$this->db->group_by('message_id');
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

I have checked so $this->session->userdata('id') outputs the same ID as my "regular" SQL-statement and it is correct.

The strange thing is that my "regular" statement returns 2, which is right. But my Codeigniter statmenet returns 3, which is obviously wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why `$this->db->where(array('read_date' => NULL));` instead of `$this->db->where('read_date', NULL);`

Comment: I've tried that also `$this->db->where('read_date', NULL);`. Why I have that is because I read it in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489453/querying-mysql-with-codeigniter-selecting-rows-where-field-is-null

Comment: OK, I see. `$this->db->last_query();` is a great debug tool sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count_all_results()` will replace your whole SELECT clause and the produced query will be this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows
FROM message
WHERE user_id_to = <your value> AND read_date IS NULL
GROUP BY message_id
```

... I'm skipping any parenthesis and escape characters of course, but they are irrelevant here.

Just put the whole thing in your `select()` call:

```
$this->db->select('id, COUNT(*) as item_count');
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('read_date IS NULL', null, false);
```

The third parameter tells him not to escape the clause...

Comment: Thanks for answer! Returns the same I'm afraid.

Comment: But that works. ^^ Perhaps poste the created SQL with `$this->db->last_query();` and your 'regular' SQL against it...

Comment: I get this when echo'ing last_query(); `SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM (`message`) WHERE `user_id_to` = '1' AND `read_date` IS NULL GROUP BY `message_id`

Comment: Now I see the problem. It is `$this->db->count_all_results();` Which doesn't provide correct in my code structure.

Comment: Ah sure.. when you use `count` you always get only one row. ^^

Answer (score 0):

It was the group by in combination with count_all_results(); Found this thread with a solution: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/131724/

Answer (score 0):

This is the way of multiple comparison in where command. to check if column data is not null 
 do it like

> 'sc_id' => TRUE

here is the complete example how I am filter  columns in where clause (Codeignitor). The last one show **Not NULL** Compression

```
$where = array('somebit' => '1', 'status' => 'Published', 'sc_id' => TRUE );
$this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think another way it could be:

```
$this->db->where('read_date IS NOT', 'NULL');
```

Haven't tested this yet, but in theory should work, someone please confirm.

Comment: That generates this sql: WHERE read_date is not 'null' (which is a text string). So go for $this->db->where('read_date IS NULL', null, false);