# Select fields that have a property set to null with codeigniter query

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am trying to create the following statement:

```js
$this->db->where('uu.usuario_grupo_id is null');
```

But it doesn't work

I also tried this:

```
$this->db->where('uu.usuario_grupo_id =', null);

$this->db->where('uu.usuario_grupo_id =', 'null');
```

none of these options returns data from fields referenced as null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13995884/2275490

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
$this->db->where(array('uu.usuario_grupo_id' => NULL));
```

produces

```
WHERE `usuario_grupo_id` IS NULL
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13995884/2275490

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->where('uu.usuario_grupo_id IS NULL', null, false);
```

For more information look [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489460/2275490